# Horizontal list with items per row

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create the following horizontal list. Please see attached. Notice how there is a horizontal list of categories 5 per row. It lists 5 on one row then goes on to the other row. Also, notice how it scroll horizontally? Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here's what I used to create the collectionView:

```
let viewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    viewLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: self.viewTitle.frame.origin.x, y: self.viewTitle.frame.origin.y + self.viewTitle.frame.height + 100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 400), collectionViewLayout: viewLayout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    self.innerView.addSubview(collectionView)
    
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    collectionView.allowsSelection = true
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(CategoryMiniCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CategoryMiniCell.identifier)
```

How do I go about listing 5 items per row?

[image]

Comment: @matt can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`.
Your layout would look something like this:

```
UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(100), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(50))

    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 5)

    let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
    return layoutSection
}
```